# How to use Pool from multiprocessing inside a SageMaker endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I have an inference_code.py that is slow if I run it in one core, so I created some multiprocessing functions to help in the time reduction of the compute-heavy tasks. This endpoint will only run once daily, so I considered an async config and an auto-scaling policy with a min instance of 0 and a max of 1.

I deploy it into SageMaker by using this code:

```
model_url = f"s3://{BUCKET}/{model_s3_key}"
container = image_uris.retrieve(region=region, framework="sklearn", version="1.0-1")
role = get_execution_role()
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
model = sagemaker.model.Model(
    image_uri=container,
    entry_point='inference_code.py',
    source_dir='code',
    role=role,
    model_data=model_url,
    code_location=f's3://{BUCKET}',
    name='test-model',
    env={
        'PROJECT': 'Test',
        'ENVIRONMENT': 'Test',
    }, 
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
)
```

Everything runs fine when deploying:

```
instance_type = "ml.c5.9xlarge"

predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer(),
    endpoint_name='test-endpoint',
    async_inference_config=asyncConfig,
)
```

When I send an invocation everything works fine until it arrives to the multiprocessing function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def multi_json(data, cores=32):
    with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        json_recom = pool.map(create_json, data)
    return json_recom
```

It breaks and sends a timeout. If I remove the code and use the function without Pool it works fine. Also, the code works fine in the notebook.

I think it might be how SageMaker creates the endpoint, but I'm unsure.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got the solution.

Instead of using Pool from multiprocessing, I got it working with concurrent.futures:

```
import concurrent.futures

def multi_json(data, cores=32):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores) as executor:
        json_recom = list(executor.map(create_json, data))
    return json_recom
```

I replaced all the `Pool` functions and It works.